# Need PHP custom function code WP All Import - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-function, wpallimport

I had a CSV with products to be imported to Woocommerce Via WP All Import Plugin.

The CSV had extra category text that needed to be removed before the hyphen ( - )

So the WP All Import team told me to use the following code in the function editor:

```
function my_cat( $subcat )
{
$subcat = explode("-", $subcat);

$new_sub = array_key_exists(1, $subcat)?$subcat[1] : $subcat[0];

return trim($new_sub);
}
```

Then call it with the snippet below:

```
[my_cat({prodlinelangname[1]})]
```

This worked fine but the problem now is that i have a new CSV that needs to remove text both before and after hyphens.

For example;

TEXT1 - TEXT2 - TEXT3

I need to remove everything from the CSV field except TEXT2.

What code can i use?

Cheers,
Victor

Comment: Please specify the error or incorrect output that you are seeing. 

$subcat = explode("-", $subcat); breaks the input into an array delimited on the hyphen character. 

The next line gets array element one if it exists, otherwise gets array element 0. 
"Text1" should return Text1. 
"Text1 - Text2" or "Text1 - Text2 - Text3" should return Text2. 
"Text1 - Text2 - Text3 - Text4 - Text5 - Text6 - Text7 ...." would return Text2 as well.

Comment: In other words, the same code

Comment: Hi LisaJ, thanks for the detailed explanation. I tried the same code and it worked. In the case of "Text1 - Text2 - Text3" or "Text1- Text 2 - Text4 - Text 5 - Text3" and i would like to only return Text3 what would the code be in this case? 

Aside to ArtisticPhoenix, thank you for your feedback too.